# Performance SVMlight Multilabel Classificaiton (Features: 1000)

Tags: performance, machine-learning, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification, svmlight

I am currently working on a multi-label classification. As classifier I use SVMlight and binarized the multi-label problem. That means in my case more than 1000 classification runs.

I have a fixed feature size of 1000, the training of the models takes now more than 3 days (2 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo, 8 GB). Has anybody experience if it is common that it takes that long or can you give me any advice how to boost the performance? Do you think a change to a high-performance machine would have a great effect?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what is the exact setup of SVMs? What hyperparameters are tested? How big is the training set?

Comment: I use SVM in Classification mode with a linear Kernel and SVMlight standard values for the other parameters. The training set consists of 20 000 documents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature normalization solved my problem, the performance was much faster after min/max ([-1,1]) normalization in the feature space.